# jq not getting expected output

Tags: jq

**My JSON looks like this.**

```
"[{
   changes": [
    {
      "change": "{users=[7], submitted=true}",
      "date": "2016-11-13T14:34:27.353Z",
      "user": "abcd"
    }
   ]
}]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{
      id: null,
      date: "2016-11-13T14:34:27.353Z",
      type: "submission",
      user: abcd,
      _processDate: todaysDate
    }
```

**JQ I tried**

```
[.[][] as $source |
$source.changes[] as $log |
$log.change |
{
  submitted: .| (scan("submitted=(?<submitted>[^,}]+)") // [""] ) | .[0],
  rejected: .| (scan("rejected=(?<rejected>[^,}]+)") // [""] ) | .[0]

} as $change |
[
  (
    select($change.submitted == "true") |
    {
      id: $source.id,
      date: $log.date,
      type: "submission",
      user: $log.user,
      _processDate: now | todate
    }),
    (select($change.rejected == "true") |
    {
      id: $source.id,
      date: $log.date,
      type: "rejection",
      user: $log.user,
      _processDate: now | todate
    }
  )
] |
.[]]
```

There could 'rejections' in the json and the output should display the rejections .
My JQ is not yielding expected output. 
Any pointers on how to fix this query.
Thank you for your help.
Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take a completely different approach and do this instead.

```
(now | todate) as $_processDate | [
    .[].changes[]
    | (.change
        | scan("\\b(submitted|rejected)=true\\b")[]
        | {submitted:"submission",rejected:"rejection"}[.]) as $type
    | {id, date, $type, user, $_processDate}
]
```

First take note of the current date at the beginning. Then determine what type of change it is. Assuming that "submitted" and "rejected" (or other "types") are mutually exclusive, easier to match on the key name. Then build up the result. This will keep the results in an array.

https://jqplay.org/s/S65ySzbF30